# Is the First Responder modified after running an NSAlert?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Sometimes when I run my application I realize that a menu is not working, as if it was not connected.

After investigation, it *seems* that the bug appears after at some point in the app, the user is asked to some text in an NSAlert.

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"enter your name"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
NSTextField *input = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 24)];
[input setStringValue:@""];
[alert setAccessoryView:input];
NSInteger button = [alert runModal];
... // do something with [input stringValue];
```

What's wrong with this ? Im using ARC. Should I "dealloc" somehow the `NSAlert` after use ?

Thanks

Comment: So what is the first responder when it stops working?

Comment: @Wain I don't know, how can I know that ? other menus are working

Comment: Well, the only one that really matters is the alert view for your question and if it was somehow still first responder. You're probably better off describing what the menu is, how it's created, what validation methods are associated and in what way it works and doesn't work (and is different to the working menus).

Comment: @Wain I simply created the menu in storyboard and associated IBAction in the ViewController. Nothing different than other menus. I have the problem by setting the window firstResponder to the view but this looked strange to me

Comment: So what menu (or is it just a menu item) isn't working?

Comment: Now it is fixed but it was 2 menu items in the same menu _toggleAxis and _toggleCoordinates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72508/discussion-between-thomas-and-wain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting up the first responder by hand after the modal.

```
[xxx.window makeFirstResponder:yyy.myView];
```

Things were really strange, I couldn't set the first responder to what it was before the call even though it was equal to myView...